# android - Starting an event with the completion of two threads running parallel

Tags: android, multithreading

I have two or more network calls in separated threads on main activity start, I want to show all data after network threads done.

```
    Thread firstNetworkCallThread=new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // network calls and get data...
        }
    });

    Thread secondNetworkCallThread =new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // network calls and get data...
        }
    });

    firstNetworkCallThread.start();
    secondNetworkCallThread.start();
```

I want these threads work parallel, and when both of them are complete, call new event to show data.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guava has a good solution for this. If you convert your `Thread`s to `ListenableFuture`s (also a Guava object) you can create a list of `ListenableFuture`s and add a callback to that list.

```
Futures.addCallback(
    Futures.allAsList(/*future1*/, /*future2*/, /*future3*/),
    new AbstractDisposableFutureCallback<List<Object>>() {
      @Override
      protected void onSuccessfulResult(List<Object> results) {
        // whatever should happen on success
      }

      @Override
      protected void onNonCancellationFailure(Throwable throwable) {
        // whatever should happen on failure
      }
    });
```

Guava also has a bunch methods such as `#successfulAsList` which only contains successful results or `#inCompletionOrder` which orders them based on when they completed and a bunch of others.

I generally tend to use Guava as it provides a fairly clean solutions to problems like these.

An example of how to creates a `ListenableFuture` is as follows:

```
ListeningExecutorService service = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10));
ListenableFuture<Object> explosion =
    service.submit(
        new Callable<Object>() {
          public Object call() {
            // get network data
            return null; // return the data
          }
        });
```